# Elizio aŭ ellaso de fina vokalo en kantado

Tags: grammar

Laŭ [PMEG](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/apostrofo/normala_uzo.html) estas kvar okazoj kie oni povas ellasi la finan vokalon de vorto, anstataŭante ĝin per apostrofo:

> 1) O-vorto se ne finiĝas per *N* aŭ *J*: *mateno* ···> *maten'*
>
> 2) Difina artikolo *la*: *de la infano* ···> *de l' infano*
>
> 3) La vorto *unu* ĉe ekkria uzo: *unu, du, tri* ···> *un', du, tri*
>
> 4) La esprimo *dank' al*, kies uzo estas fiksita per tradicio.

Do, mi supozas ke mi povus traduki la jenan linion de la kanto [Chandelier](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8DS-h67qEiY&t=1m50s) tiel ĉi:

*one two three, one two three, drink* ···> *un' du tri, un' du tri, drinki*

Tamen, laŭ la supraj lingvaj klarigoj, mi ne povus uzi *drink'* anstataŭ *drinki*, kvankam estus pli bone el ritma vidpunkto. Nu, mia demando estas ĉu tia rimedo estas tolerebla se temas pri kantado? Ŝajnas al mi ke la senco estus klara ene de la kanto-kunteksto.

Mi jam scias pri almenaŭ unu kanto kiu uzas "strangan" rimedon, supozeble fare de Japana Esperanto-Instituto por la manga-filmo [Patema inverse](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qKc3RsmxQcw&t=0m20s):

*Jen unu jen la **ali'** tiritaj palpe* ... anstataŭ ... *Jen unu jen la **alia** tiritaj palpe*

*Jen unu jen la **ali'** kruciĝas vortoj* ... anstataŭ ... *Jen unu jen la **alia** kruciĝas vortoj*

Comment: Mi ne komprenas la frazojn de Patema inverse. Ĉu akuzativo mankas en la dua frazo? Ĉu eble *ali'* signifas *aliaj* en la unua frazo?

Comment: Laŭ mi ne mankas akuzativo. Kie ĝi mankas laŭ vi? Mi pensas ke _ali'_ anstataŭas la singularan _alia_, ĉar temas pri _jen...jen_ frazo, en kiu ambaŭ estas _tiritaj_, iafoje unu kaj alifoje la alia (_jen unu jen la alia_).

Comment: Ah, mi nun komprenas; *Jen unu jen la alia tiritaj palpe=jen unu tirita palpe, jen la alia tirita palpe* kaj *Jen unu jen la alia kruciĝas vortoj=Jen kruciĝas unu vorto, jen kruciĝas la alia vorto*. Korektu min, se mi malpravas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kiel klarigas svendvn, mi kredas ke en ĉi tiu okazo oni ja povus uzi *drink’* kiel mallongigon de *drinko*. Ankaŭ via ekzemplo de la japana kanto povus esti konsiderata kiel mallongigo de *alio*, kvankam tio estus malofta vorto.

Tamen por tradukado de kanto ne necesas strikte sekvi la vortojn de la originalo, kaj mi volis proponi alian ideon. Estas [mojosa traduko de tiu kanto en la franca](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=alqS9olkeGo), kaj tie ĝi estas «un, deux, trois et moi je bois». La ripeto de «one, two, three» estas anstataŭigita de frazo. Mi pensas ke oni povus fari simile en esperanto kiel ĉi tio:

> Un’, du, tri kaj drinkas mi

Ĝenerala punkto pri la reguloj estas ke ne estas PMEG-polico kiu arestos vin se vi ne obeas. Do efektive vi povas fari kion ajn vi volas por via traduko, kaj la nura demando estas ĉu la traduko plaĉos aŭ ne. Se sufiĉe da homoj ne sekvos tiujn regulojn pri elizio la lingvo simple ŝanĝiĝos. Tamen en ĉi tiu okazo mi dirus ke tiu regulo estas vaste akceptita kaj la plejmulto de la aŭskultantoj trovus la kanton malkomforta se la regulo ne estas respektata.

Comment: Parenteze se vi komprenas la francan la tradukisto de tiu franca versio faris ankaŭ filmeton kun klarigoj de la traduko. Eble tio povus inspiri vin por via traduko :) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9-fHd1KraFo

Comment: Tre interesa propono. Tiu franca tradukisto tute pravas, nomante la tradukon de kanto per la nomo "tradaptado" (tradukado kaj adaptado). Bedaŭrinde mi ne scipovas la francan sed iafoje kaptas la sencon. Dankon pro viaj inspiraj ligiloj.

Answer (score 3):

Multaj verboj ankaŭ havas substantivan version. Do oni komprenus

> un' du tri, un' du tri, drink' = unu du tri, unu du tri, **drinko**.

Tio ne gravas en *Chandelier*, sed tio povas gravi en aliaj situacioj. Uzu la metodon singarde.